# Faciliter la navigation et la visualisation des/dans... les résultats ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, coordination

Tout est dans le titre mais le voici formulé :

Quel connecteur choisir après une suite de mots appelant des connecteurs différents ?

"Faciliter la navigation et la visualisation dans les résultats" ou bien "Faciliter la navigation et la visualisation des résultats" ?

Ici "navigation" fonctionne bien avec "des", mais il y a d'autres cas...
Veuillez excuser le terme de "connecteurs", je suis vraiment ignorant en grammaire.

Comment: _des_ est plus esthétique, mais je ne saurais vous le justifier grammaticalement. (Effectivement "navigation" appelle _dans_ alors que visualisation appelle _des_ ; quand les deux sont présents, je mettrais _des_ sans pouvoir vous le justifier).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C'est un problème auquel on est souvent confronté en rédigeant des textes, en effet.

Bien qu'il n'y ait pas de règle absolue ou de solution miracle, on peut observer ceci :

- il est souvent (probablement pas *toujours*) maladroit de mettre en facteur la manière de connecter les deux structures hétérogènes, même en utilisant, ce qui est un peu meilleur à l'oreille, la construction du dernier groupe cité (pour l'exemple d'aujourd'hui, *Faciliter la navigation et la visualisation des résultats*).
- il est malheureusement tout aussi maladroit, la plupart du temps, de faire la répétition explicite des parties communes (*Faciliter la navigation dans les résultats et la visualisation des résultats*)

La solution se trouve souvent dans une reformulation évitant cette incompatibilité, mais il existe également la possibilité de mettre en facteur une partie plus réduite, qui permette de ne pas trop se répéter.

Ici, par exemple :

> *Faciliter la navigation dans les résultats ainsi que leur visualisation*

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour vos indications sur les usages. Il n'y a donc effectivement pas de règle comme le disait @Alexis Pigeon. La solution est de changer de construction et d'utiliser "leur" pour reprendre "les résultats". Merci !

Answer (score 3):

*Faciliter la navigation et la visualisation **dans les** résultats* sonne vraiment faux.

*Faciliter la navigation et la visualisation **des** résultats* est moins pire, mais pas top à mon avis.

Mes propositions:

- inverser *navigation* et *visualisation*

> Faciliter la visualisation et la navigation dans les résultats

- placer *dans les résultats* plus tôt dans la phrase

> Faciliter la navigation dans les résultats et leur visualisation

- introduire un nouveau verbe

> Faciliter la navigation dans les résultats et améliorer leur visualisation

Je ne pense pas qu'il y ait de règle de grammaire établie, c'est vraiment "à l'oreille" qu'on choisira une préposition ou une autre (ou aucune).

Comment: C'est vrai que certaines constructions sonnent faux, mais comme vous dites "sonnent" faux. Choisir l'un ou l'autre des connecteurs pourrait être correct du point de vue de la construction. Est-ce vrai qu'il n'y a pas de règle établie ? Je ne connais pas le nom de ce cas et je ne sais donc pas pour quelle règle chercher. En ce qui est des changements de construction, ils sont bien sûr élégants mais c'est le connecteur qui est intéressant.

Answer (score 3):

On s'autorise assez souvent l'emploi groupé de deux verbes ou deux noms dont le complément devrait être introduit par des prépositions différentes. Il se peut aussi qu'un verbe soit suivi d'une préposition et l'autre non.

Dans ces cas, la seule façon de ne pas écorcher les oreilles de ceux à qui vous parlez (ou écrivez) c'est d'« accorder » avec la dernière entité.

On dit ainsi :

> Faciliter la navigation et la visualisation des résultats.

car on dirait « faciliter la visualisation des résultats ». La tournure « *faciliter la navigation et la visualisation dans les données* » est horrible (« visualisation dans » produit un choc). « *Faciliter la navigation et la visualisation des données* » n'est pas grammaticalement parfait, mais à peu près tout le monde l'emploie et l'accepte.

Autres exemples :

- > Trie et réponds à ces lettres.

  Dans ce cas il s'agit de « trier ces lettres » et de « répondre à ces lettres ».
- > L'accès et la modification des données se fait en deux étapes.

  On considère ici « l'accès aux données » et « la modification des données ».

Ces tournures ne sont pas parfaites, mais assurément c'est bien mieux dans ce sens que dans l'autre.

Il faut garder en tête qu'il est souvent possible de contourner la difficulté en utilisant de façon plus élégante des pronoms.

> Trie les lettres et réponds-y.
>
> L'accès aux données et leur modification.

Malheureusement, ce n'est pas toujours aussi facile.

Comment: Vous conseillez alors d'accorder avec la dernière entité, c'est en effet une bonne façon de garder une tournure élégante. Mais alors s'il n'y a pas de règle, l'écriture "Faciliter la navigation et la visualisation dans les données" est-elle correcte au sens grammatical ?

Comment: Ce qui est certain c'est que « *Faciliter la navigation et la visualisation dans les données* » est horrible (« visualisation dans » produit un choc). « *Faciliter la navigation et la visualisation des données* » n'est pas grammaticalement parfait, mais à peu près tout le monde l'emploie et l'accepte.